# How to properly apply a loop for JSON, if it is not an array?

Tags: java, json, pojo

How can I parse JSON in the following format. I need to apply a loop to get the data from the keys 'n1', 'n2', 'n3' etc. I generated POJO classes, but since 'n1', 'n2', 'n3' etc is not an array, I cannot use a loop.

```
{
  "data": {
    "n1": {
      "bla": "0",
      "bla2": "0",
      "bla3": [
        {
          "zzz1": "0",
          "zzz2": "0",
          "zzz3": [
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "n2": {
      "bla": "0",
      "bla2": "0",
      "bla3": [
        {
          "zzz1": "0",
          "zzz2": "0",
          "zzz3": [
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
          ]
        }
      ]

    },
    "n3": {
      "bla": "0",
      "bla2": "0",
      "bla3": [
        {
          "zzz1": "0",
          "zzz2": "0",
          "zzz3": [
            "0",
            "0",
            "0"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

POJO:

```
public class MyPojo
{
    ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Data> getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    class Data
    {
        private N1 n1;

        private N3 n3;

        private N2 n2;

        public N1 getN1 ()
        {
            return n1;
        }

        public N3 getN3 ()
        {
            return n3;
        }


        public N2 getN2 ()
        {
            return n2;
        }
    }

    class N1
    {

        private String bla;
        private String bla2;   
        private ArrayList<Bla3> bla3 = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getBla ()
        {
            return bla;
        }

        public String getBla2 ()
        {
            return bla2;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bla3> getBla3 ()
        {
            return bla3;
        }
    }

    class N2
    {
        private String bla;
        private String bla2;
        private ArrayList<Bla3> bla3 = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getBla ()
        {
            return bla;
        }

        public String getBla2 ()
        {
            return bla2;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bla3> getBla3 ()
        {
            return bla3;
        }
    }

    class N3
    {
        private String bla;
        private String bla2;
        private ArrayList<Bla3> bla3 = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getBla ()
        {
            return bla;
        }

        public String getBla2 ()
        {
            return bla2;
        }

        public ArrayList<Bla3> getBla3 ()
        {
            return bla3;
        }
    }

    class Bla3
    {
        private String zzz1;

        private String zzz2;

        private String[] zzz3;

        public String getZzz1 ()
        {
            return zzz1;
        }

        public String getZzz2 ()
        {
            return zzz2;
        }

        public String[] getZzz3 ()
        {
            return zzz3;
        }
    }
}
```

POJO I did myself. Is he correct? Android Studio does not issue errors, but the cycle does not work, since it is not an array. The error 'Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT' appears.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Ок, just minutes.

Comment: Added POJO, JAVA code did not add, since there is just an ordinary loop.

Comment: @androbv n1,n2,n3 are json objects. you cannot extract them with loops.

Comment: Thank you, I just have little experience...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson as the JSON parser you can use the @JsonAnySetter annotation to get called for each of the properties not in your class. This would allow you to perform the same action for each property - effectively looping around them.

Simplifying your json to...

```
{
    "n1": {"a":"one"},
    "n2": {"a":"two"},
    "n3": {"a":"three"}
}
```

given a class Data to map the values of n1, n2 and n3 into

```
public class Data {

    private String a;

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Then you could use the @JsonAnySetter like so to populate a map, the keys would be n1, n2, n3 and values would be Data objects with a = one, two and three

```
public class MyPojo 
{
    Map<String, Data> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    public List<Data> getDataAsAList () {
        return new ArrayList<Data>(dataMap.values());
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addData(String fieldName, Data value) {
        dataMap.put(fieldName, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, I have never used Jackson, but I will try the option that you suggested.